# turtle function doesn't work in pycharm

Tags: pycharm

I am a beginner at `python`, I am currently using `pycharm` to write code.
However, the graphic created by the turtle function cannot be permanent, it only appeared for half second and disappeared with

> Process finished with exit code 0

Can anyone please explain how can I make the graphics permanent?
The code is below with a simple hello but I cannot make it work

```
from turtle import *
screen = Screen()
screen.setup(400, 400)
screen.bgcolor("#e6faff")
color("#ff6666")
style = ("Arial", 40, "bold")
write("Hello", font=style, align='center')
hideturtle()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just simply add `done()` in your code to hold the output of turtle graphics in python.

So your code look like ...

```
from turtle import *
screen = Screen()
screen.setup(400, 400)
screen.bgcolor("#e6faff")
color("#ff6666")
style = ("Arial", 40, "bold")
write("Hello", font=style, align='center')
hideturtle()
done()
```